# vue upgrade - migration from vue2 to vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, migration

I am upgrading my vue2 project to vue3 using `vue upgrade`.

the upgrade of plugins

- @vue/cli-plugin-router
- @vue/cli-plugin-vuex
- @vue/cli-service

worked well.

when trying to update plugin `@vue/cli-plugin-babel` I run into the following issue:

```bash
ts-ui git:(vue3) ✗ vue upgrade                       
 WARN  There are uncommitted changes in the current repository, it's recommended to commit or stash them first.
? Still proceed? Yes
✔  Gathering package information...
  Name                          Installed       Wanted          Latest          Command to upgrade
  @vue/cli-plugin-babel         4.5.19          4.5.19          5.0.8           vue upgrade @vue/cli-plugin-babel
  @vue/cli-plugin-eslint        4.5.19          4.5.19          5.0.8           vue upgrade @vue/cli-plugin-eslint
  vue-cli-plugin-bootstrap-vue  0.6.0           0.6.0           0.8.2           vue upgrade vue-cli-plugin-bootstrap-vue
? Continue to upgrade these plugins? Yes
Upgrading @vue/cli-plugin-babel from 4.5.19 to 5.0.8
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.19
npm ERR! Found: @vue/cli-service@5.0.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-service
npm ERR!   peer @vue/cli-service@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0-0" from @vue/cli-plugin-router@5.0.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-router
npm ERR!     @vue/cli-plugin-router@"^5.0.8" from @vue/cli-service@5.0.8
npm ERR!     dev @vue/cli-plugin-router@"~5.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @vue/cli-service@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0-0" from @vue/cli-plugin-vuex@5.0.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-vuex
npm ERR!     @vue/cli-plugin-vuex@"^5.0.8" from @vue/cli-service@5.0.8
npm ERR!     dev @vue/cli-plugin-vuex@"~5.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (the root project, @vue/cli-plugin-babel)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @vue/cli-service@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0-0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.19
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!   dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^4.5.15" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @vue/cli-service@4.5.19
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-service
npm ERR!   peer @vue/cli-service@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0-0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.19
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!     dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^4.5.15" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/udos/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/udos/.npm/_logs/2023-08-14T21_22_58_910Z-debug-0.log
 ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error @vue/cli-plugin-babel@~5.0.8
```

*note: I also tried to do this using node v16 and v18 without success.*

any suggestions how to fix this?

thx

Comment: I know you're using Vue CLI, so I didn't want to put this in as an answer. We migrated all of our projects from Vue CLI to Vite, and couldn't be happier. Way simpler, and crazy fast.

If this is an option for you, it's worth trying it out.

https://vitejs.dev/

https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-vue-cli-to-vite/

Comment: thank you so much @MattP! your link broght me much farther than everything else I tried so far! so after migrating from vue-cli to vite you would upgrade vue2 to vue3?

Comment: yes, that's a good plan. Vite works with both, so at least you know if you're solving an issue with Vite first. Then when that builds and runs as expected, Vue3 will be a much cleaner migration. Our migration from Vue2 to Vue3 was more a matter of finding components that worked with Vue3. That's less of an issue today, but still means some libraries are left behind. Ultimately we found good replacements for everything we needed.